# Trouble lining up ordered list

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have [this site](http://sdms.co.nz/index4.html#johnfrye) with a list of items under a block of text, but I can't get it to line up the list underneath the block of text, then put the DIV #contact to go underneath the list. I'm not sure if I've formed my HTML poorly, or am missing something in my CSS.

This is the relevant CSS (I think):

```
#johnfrye ul li {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.45em;
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-left:5px;
    list-style:inside;
    list-style-position:inside;
    list-style-type:disc;
    margin-left:40px;
}

#contact {
    position:absolute;
    right:auto;
    left:auto;
    margin-left:30%;
    margin-right:30%;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:1.25em;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed your UL styling to the below, and i also agree with samyoul - give the UL a class and style the class (in case you use another UL that you want to be styled differently).

```
ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: auto auto 5em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for these helpful tips. Now I'm finding the text underneath the images is over running and I can't find what is causing it. It should have the person's name on one line, then their job on the next.

Comment: do you mean the their names in bold? you can just add a <br /> tag like this <h2>
Mr John Frye
<br>
General Surgeon
</h2>

Comment: also, if you don't want the text to float under the photos, put the text into a div that floats to the left and has a width of something like 85%

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a bit that's done wrong with your HTML and CSS.

To fix your specific problem change your CSS, add the following:

```
ul.listofstuff {
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Change your HTML section to this:

```
<ul class="listofstuff">
    <li>Anal and rectal bleeding</li>
    <li>Investigation of abdominal pain </li>
    <li> Colorectal cancer and polyps</li>
    <li>Inflammatory bowel disease</li>
    <li>Haemorrhoids, fistula and fissure</li>
    <li> Pelvic floor disorders </li>
    <li>Diverticular disease</li>
    <li>Pilonidal isease </li>
    <li>Biliary pain and cholecystitis </li>
    <li>Hernia – inguinal and incisional</li>
</ul>
```

I'll give you a tip to help you on your way. Do not rely on **float** and **position** to format your page, these have their proper uses but not in the way you are trying to use them.